# Need nth-child() formula

Tags: jquery

I am trying to copy bunch of div one by one and paste it inside the respective list using the below code

```
var index=1;
$('.storycontent').each(function () {
  ('#story-tabs ul li:nth-child(n)').after($(this).html());
  index++;
});

    <ul>
      <li class="first current">Story1</li>
      <li class="first">Story2</li>
      <li class="first">Story3</li>
   </ul>
```

After executing the above code the ouput what i get is

```
<ul>
  <li class="first current">Story1</li>
      <div id="one">some content</div>
      <div id="two">some content</div>
      <div id="three">some content</div>
  <li class="first">Story2</li>
      <div id="one">some content</div>
      <div id="two">some content</div>
      <div id="three">some content</div>
  <li class="first">Story3</li>
      <div id="one">some content</div>
      <div id="two">some content</div>
      <div id="three">some content</div>
</ul>
```

But I require

```
<ul>
  <li class="first current">Story1</li>
      <div id="one">some content</div>
  <li class="first">Story2</li>
      <div id="two">some content</div>
  <li class="first">Story3</li>
      <div id="three">some content</div>
</ul>
```

Comment: That's not a valid markup. `ul` element should only have `li` child elements.

Comment: jquery code is also not valid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a start, you need to fix your markup, but I know what you're getting at. You can use `eq` for this.

```
$('.storycontent').each(function (index) {
  ('#story-tabs ul li').eq(index).after($(this).html());
});
```